# Specifying path to pdb symbol file in cmake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, pdb-files

I want to change the pdb symbol file path according to this [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998269%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and set `/PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%`. However, if I write

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} /DEBUG
    /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%")
```

and check the result in the project properties, it reads `/PDBALTPATH:%%_PDB%%`.
Leaving the percent signs out results in `/PDBALTPATH:_PDB`.

How do I achieve `/PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%` ?

Patterns I've tried so far (all of them turn a % into %% ):

1. `/PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%`
2. `/PDBALTPATH:_PDB`
3. `/PDBALTPATH:%25_PDB%25`
4. `/PDBALTPATH:%%_PDB%%`

Comment: This looks like a bug without an easy workaround to me.

Answer (score 2):

Since CMake 3.1 there is a `TARGET_PDB_FILE_NAME` generator expression ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_PDB_FILE_NAME)). It evaluates just to the name of the file, without the path.

So, you can achieve the effect of `%_PDB%` by replacing it with the actual name of the pdb file at generation-time. You'll need to specify the linker flags for each target of interest, though.

The command will be like so

```
# Suppose
add_library(foo ${foo_sources}) # or add_executable

# Then
target_link_options(foo PRIVATE /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PDBALTPATH:$<TARGET_PDB_FILE_NAME:foo>)
```